# Read Dynamics 365/CRM from Azure Logic Apps

Tags: dynamics-crm, azure-logic-apps, dynamics-365

I have an Azure Logic App that is triggered upon a sales/purchase order record being updated in Dynamics 365 (online).

I grab all the sales order fields and then I grab all the sales order line fields and I send them to a Web API app as JSON parameters. Now I need product fields for each sales order line.

I currently send the sales order and sales order lines as separate parameters. I would like to combine the sales order, sales order lines and products into one JSON payload.

I'm having difficulty figuring out how to pull in the product for each sales order line and then combining it all into one JSON payload.

How would I do this?

I've been investigating but so far no luck.

Comment: when you send json to webapi app why not send product fields for each sales order line as well?
If not you can always connect back from azure logic apps to crm and get product fields for each sales order.

Comment: Thanks @AnkUser Exactly. How do I do that? =)